# Will there by any further breaking changes in Angular2

Tags: angular

Our developer is hesitating to move on to angular2 because of constant breaking changes and lack of 3rd party packages.

But now that Angular2 is out of beta, would there be any further breaking changes?

regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is the sort of thing you ask the maintainers of the package (ie: the developers committing their time to the project). Asking the SO community will result in opinion-based answers.

Comment: Angular2 is still only available as a release candidate, I don't think you can rule more "breaking changes"

Comment: might be naming changes not more than that or little syntax changes  like ngSwitchWhen can be ngSwitchCase

Comment: @DevNull opinions do matter and it would help me in taking an informed decision.

Comment: @Sunny sure, but opinionated questions are discouraged on SO and usually just closed out. For opinionated questions other platforms than SO are a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is about predicting the future. My crystal ball is a bit foggy today but I try anyway ;-)

The Angular team will try hard to avoid breaking changes. They were already trying hard during beta. With each phase the importance of avoiding breaking changes rises.

While there were adding major building blocks that were still missing previously in Angular, they discovered architecture issues that made it difficult to implement these new features, and therefore they fixed it instead of making themselves and all developers living with the sub-optimal solution.

Now the major building blocks are in place. This is why they announced RC phase.

If they now discover **major** problems in the architecture, I'm pretty sure they will still fix it, even when this causes breaking changes. For minor issues, not breaking any existing code will be more important.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it clarifies a lot of doubts. On a second note, does it make sense to start the dev on Ang2 or proceed with Ang1 and then upgrade to Ang2 next year?

Comment: It was mentioned in a talk on ng-conf that there is support for Ng1 to create Ng2 style components which are easy to port to Ng2 later. There is also support to integrate Ng2 components and services into an Ng1 application. I haven't tried any of these options myself though. In my opinion it's quite safe to use Ng2 now. The main disadvantage is the lack of availability of 3rd-party tools and components (growing daily but IMHO currently the biggest disadvantage of Ng2 compared to Ng1)

Comment: What should also be considered is that `Http` and the `Router` are not considered as part of Angular. They are currently developed in the Angular GitHub repo for convenience but are supposed to be moved out as separate modules. The RC status is not for these modules AFAIK only for Angular2 core.